# iOS Swift - Autoscroll UILabel from Right to Left

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

These two columns needed to be scrolled automatically (like marquee). But I am having problem to do this. I found two solutions but unfortunately none of these worked.

1. https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel
2. https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    let label = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.frame = CGRectMake(320, 100, 200, 60)
    label.text = "This is my music line"
    self.view!.addSubview(label)
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.LabelAnimate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func LabelAnimate() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, delay: 0.0, options: .TransitionNone, animations: {() -> Void in
    self.label.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 100, 200, 60)
        }, completion: {(isDone: Bool) -> Void in
            self.label.frame = CGRectMake(320, 100, 200, 60)
    })
}
}
```